# Best approaches to store push notifications temporarly

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

i am trying to implement push notifications for a news application using FCM. so i want to use Inbox style notification when there is 2 or more notification pending. and normal notification for single notifications .so we need some-kind of storage for storing old push messages that are not clicked by the user. so is there any approaches or any api available for achieving this

Answer (score 0):

Using this example

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

you can obtain `remoteMessage` using

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

}
```

the data:

`remoteMessage.getData()`

You can store the values using preferences of application

```
SharedPreferences PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
Editor editor = prf.edit();
editor.putString(youdataname,yourvalue);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: yeah. SharedPreferences has limits you know,there will be an array  of messages  i need store.so i  looked into snappyDB ( key-value database). but i want to know that is there any better options or built in API for this.

Comment: use SQLiteDataBase, so you easily insert, delete and retrive data.